# Can't find materials in .blend file

Tags: materials

I downloaded a material from http://matrep.parastudios.de/index.php. By my understandings you just need to download the .blend file, open your project, go to append and find in the .blend file the material. But when I open the file, it's empty.

Maybe anyone had this problem and can help me out? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Try opening the .blend file itself, selecting an object, and going as if to apply a material to it—that should show you what materials there are. If there aren't any, then that's why they're not showing up in Append.

Comment: Did you open the .blend file before and then save it? If the materials weren't used by anything, they could have gotten deleted. (You can tell if something is _going_ to be deleted because it will have a '0' next to its name. To tell Blender you actually want to keep it, hit the 'F' button.)

Answer (score 2):

I tested downloading a material there myself, and had similiar problems like you. Neither appending nor linking were possible. On opening the file itself, blender complains about *File format is not supported*. So I guess you just have to look for another material. Maybe this site is outdated.

Try this link: [Resources for blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender).

Comment: I opened one (cooled lava) file and I received a cube with a difuse color and nothing else. I think it is not a good site to downloading materials.