# Materials from Openmaterial repository don't load

Tags: materials, append

Good morning, I was searching some free material I needed, and found the openmaterial repository (http://matrep.parastudios.de/).

The site seems a legitimate repository so I've tried to dowlonad some files, and to append the materials in the usual way, but every single time the append doesn't work: Blender keeps "Listing dirs" endlessly and when I click the "Append from Library" I get a message of error like this one:

*'/home/myname/Downloads/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64/DownloadedMaterials/www.matrep.parastudios.de/black-white_floor.blend/': nothing indicated*

Now, if it was only for the single "black-white_floor" file, I would move on, but it happened for every single material of the 11 I downloaded.

They all have some reasonable dimension (from around 250kB up to 1.9MB) so they seem to be downloaded correctly.

And this happens both with Blender 2.76 and with the more recent Blender 2.79

So I wonder if anyone knows the reason of this. Thanks.

Edit: I found the same problem in this question, so it appears to be something very old. [Can't find materials in .blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89147/cant-find-materials-in-blend-file)
The crazy thing is that the site is acutally referred as repository from http://www.blender-materials.org/ which is the first site popping up when I do researches for free material.

So, I guess that if the problem exists since august 2017, there isn't a solution.